# After upgrading spring boot from 1.x to 2.x getting error com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The "variant" data type is not supported

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, jpa

```
om.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The "variant" data type is not supported.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:191)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1444)
```

Getting above error after upgrading my Spring boot application from 1.x to 2.x

Answer (score 0):

Also upgrade driver version with latest version.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>8.4.1.jre14</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: That worked but i had to use jre8

Now getting Operator IN on abc requires a Collection argument, found class java.lang.String in method public abstract java.util.List com.xyz.repositories.InfoRepositories.findByStatusIn(java.lang.String).

Comment: You can create a new question by adding the related code.